# Modal View Controller making background black

Tags: objective-c, xcode, modalviewcontroller

I am launching a Modal View Controller from a view controller.  Everything in the modal view controller is displayed fine, except that the parent view controller goes black.  When the modal view controller is dismissed, the parent is drawn.  Can anybody point me where I am going wrong?  Here is the code I am using:

```
modalVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: modalVC];

[currentViewController presentModalViewController: self.navigationController animated: YES];
self.navigationController.view.frame = CGRectMake(200, 200, 320, 540);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem finally.  It was my mistake.

This is the culprit:

```
self.navigationController.view.frame = CGRectMake(200, 200, 320, 540);
```

It should be:

```
self.navigationController.view.superview.frame = CGRect(200,200,320, 540);
```

Comment: I was doing this in viewDidLoad 
`[self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];` 
I guess it was shrinking the view to 0,0 in size.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of this line.

```
modalVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
```

From [UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIModalPresentationFormSheet) (emphasis mine):

> `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`
>
> The width and height of the presented view are smaller than those of the screen and the view is centered onscreen. If the device is in a landscape orientation and the keyboard is visible, the position of the view is adjusted upward so the view remains visible. **All uncovered areas are dimmed to prevent the user from interacting with them.**

Comment: Thank you very much for the response.  The other areas are not dimmed, but they just turned black until the popover is dismissed.

Comment: I found the problem finally.  It was my mistake.  This is the culprit: `self.navigationController.view.frame = CGRectMake(200, 200, 320, 540); `
It should be: `self.navigationController.view.superview.frame = CGRect(200,200,320, 540);`